# Why the code block is not Autovectorized by VC2013

Tags: c, auto-vectorization

The code block is from mozilla firefox's qcms transform_util.c

```
    void build_output_lut(struct curveType *trc,
                uint16_t **output_gamma_lut, size_t *output_gamma_lut_length)
{
        if (trc->type == PARAMETRIC_CURVE_TYPE) {
                float gamma_table[256];
                uint16_t i;
                uint16_t *output = malloc(sizeof(uint16_t)*256);

                if (!output) {
                        *output_gamma_lut = NULL;
                        return;
                }

                compute_curve_gamma_table_type_parametric(gamma_table, trc->parameter, trc->count);
                *output_gamma_lut_length = 256;
                for(i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                        output[i] = (uint16_t)(gamma_table[i] * 65535);
                }
                *output_gamma_lut = output;
        } else {
                if (trc->count == 0) {
                        *output_gamma_lut = build_linear_table(4096);
                        *output_gamma_lut_length = 4096;
                } else if (trc->count == 1) {
                        float gamma = 1./u8Fixed8Number_to_float(trc->data[0]);
                        *output_gamma_lut = build_pow_table(gamma, 4096);
                        *output_gamma_lut_length = 4096;
                } else {
                        //XXX: the choice of a minimum of 256 here is not backed by any theory, 
                        //     measurement or data, however it is what lcms uses.
                        *output_gamma_lut_length = trc->count;
                        if (*output_gamma_lut_length < 256)
                                *output_gamma_lut_length = 256;

                        *output_gamma_lut = invert_lut(trc->data, trc->count, *output_gamma_lut_length);
                }
        }

}
```

For this loop:

```
            for(i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                    output[i] = (uint16_t)(gamma_table[i] * 65535);
            }
```

VC2013 will show:

> e:\mozilla\hg\nightly\mozilla-central\gfx\qcms\transform_util.c(490) : info C5002: 由于“500”，循环未向量化

MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658585.aspx) shows:

```
// Code 500 is emitted if the loop has non-vectorizable flow.
// This can include "if", "break", "continue", the conditional 
// operator "?", or function calls.
// It also encompasses correct definition and use of the induction
// variable "i", in that the increment "++i" or "i++" must be the last
// statement in the loop.
```

But the loop above has no if/break/continue, I don't know why it can't be vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is due to the fact that variable "i" lies in scope of "if"-statement. Thus it does not belong entirely to "for-loop" scope like it would have been in

> for(int i = 0; /* etc. */
>   At such, the compiler's logic would have been like: "I need not only to make gammatable filles with needed values, but to assign same value to "i" as at loop end". Therefore, no vectorization.

Comment: I try to put uint16_t i out of if-statement, but also produce the warning. And I don't understand your last part's meaning.

Comment: Ok, in short: IMHO to be vectorized, variable "i" must be declared inside for-loop like in the MSDN example. Last part's meaning:
MSDN example: fill array with values, variable "i" has for-loop scope -> not accessible out of it, can be dropped in the process.
Your code: fill array with values, variable "i" has "if" scope -> accessible beyond + has to have value as if for-loop actually took place -> can not vectorize